# Create single HTML / markdown file using Sandcastle Documentation

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

simple question here.

I'm using Sandcastle Help File Builder to generate documentation of a C# project in Markdown or HTML format. My issue is it's creating a separate .md / .html file for every item that's documented. Is there any way to force it to generate a single large file containing all the documentation similar to how Visual Studio outputs one single XML file, or at minimum using a directory system to at least structure the output a little better rather than have one folder with ~200 markdown / html files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML part of the question, it is possible to open the generated `index.html` file in a browser (may need to enable scripting for the page to work correctly), then save it as a single file in [MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) format. According to the linked page, the current versions of most major browsers support MHTML nowadays.